# Error message with Pear when trying to send mail

Tags: php, email, pear

I'm trying to send an email using PHP Pear.  I have everything install correctly I assume.  But I am now getting the following error message?  Does anyone know what is wrong?

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method PEAR_Error::send()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a similar complaint regarding PEAR mail, check out this link on PHP Freaks: http://www.phpfreaks.com/forums/index.php/topic,227059.0.html?PHPSESSID=0ole7isgoaahcdn4tg0k7r4li4